# Finding a way to open up a specific Brave window at a specific time every day

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a use case where I want to open up a specific window in the Brave browser every day at a certain time - and have it maximized and focused. To give you specifics, I'm trying to remember to read my list of goals and values that I've set for myself when I wake up in the morning. This is stored in a google docs window that I have opening daily at 5:00am using a Chrome extension. This all works great, except for the fact that it ends up minimized and often times I don't see it until later in the day.

Anything that would solve this use case?

Comment: Try Task Scheduler and use the parameters to open maximized

Comment: This worked, except - it starts maximized - but it does not start in the foreground. Any ideas on that? I've looked up a few solutions - turning off UAC, start with highest permissions, and Run as an individual user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you let it run for Any User (and even if not logged in). For you, however, log in. Also set to run with Highest Privileges.

You should not be challenged for UAC since you will have to provide Admin Credentials to set Run with Highest Privileges.

These should work - we use these settings for clients who are standard users and all works.

Set your other parameters (open maximized, and so on). There are other settings in the other tabs (look at what Trigger can do).

[image: Task Scheduler Settings]